# antisymmetric ways to arrange m+n cars

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We want to lines up m+n cars. There are m P cars and n F cars.
Supposing that m+n is even. How many antisymmetric ways to arrange the cars are there? ("Antisymmetric" means that if k-th car from the left is P then k-th form the right must be F, and other way round)

Comment: What are your attempts in solving this problem ?

Comment: I have no idea...I an not sure we can assume n = m or not

Answer (score 1):

We must have $m=n$. I will assume that any two P-cars are indistinguishable, as are any two F-cars. If they are all distinguishable, multiply the answer we will get by $(m!)^2$.

For any of the first $m$ positions, we have $2$ choices, a $P$ or an $F$. Then the last $m$ positions are determined.  So there are $2^m$ choices.